# Derivative of $f(P^{-1}HP)$ w.r.t. H

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, tensors

Given

- $f:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
- $H\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a variable
- $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a constant
- $f':\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the gradient of $f$ i.e. $f_{ij}'(H)=\frac{\delta}{\delta h_{ij}}f(H)$

Is there a matrix expression for $\frac{d}{dH}f(P^{-1}HP)$ ?

Is it perhaps $P^{-1}f'(P^{-1}HP)P$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have calculated the gradient $(G)$ of a function in terms of the variable $Y$
$$
G = \frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}
\quad\implies\quad
df = G:dY
$$
where the colon denotes the trace product, i.e. $\;M:N = {\rm Tr}(M^TN)$

You are then told that $Y$ is not independent, but is actually a function of another matrix $X,\,$ e.g. 
$$Y=AXB$$
Calculate the gradient $(J)$ with respect to this new variable, by expanding the differential and then performing a change of variables. 
$$\eqalign{
df &= G:dY \\
   &= G:A\,\,dX\,B \\
   &= A^TGB^T:dX \\
   &= J:dX \\
J &= A^TGB^T \;=\; \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} \\
}$$
In terms of components, this result can be written as
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{il}}
 &= \sum_j\sum_k A^T_{ij}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y_{jk}}\right)B^T_{kl} \\
}$$